# How to plot multiple variables within a tibble

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here is my tibble:

```
domain_diversity 

A tibble: 81 × 8    

YEAR   REGION protected_status data data_wide dom_richness
    <int>  <chr>  <chr>           <list> <list>   <int>
1   1999 DRY TORT                0 <tibble [339 × 2]> <tibble [1 × 339]>          
# ... with 71 more rows, and 2 more variables: dom_simpson <dbl>, dom_shannon <dbl>
```

I am trying to plot "dom_richness", "dom_simpson", and "don_shannon" on the same plot but by "REGION" ["DRY TORT" and "FLA KEYS"] and by "protected_status" [0,1,2, all]

So far I have been able to plot by diversity for each region but can't seem to separate by "protected_status" level.

```
ggplot(data = domain_diversity, aes(x = YEAR)) +
geom_point(aes(y = dom_richness, color = "dom_richness")) +
geom_point(aes(y = dom_simpson, color = "dom_simpson")) +
geom_point(aes(y = dom_shannon, color = "dom_shannon")) +
geom_line(aes(y = dom_richness, color = "dom_richness")) +
geom_line(aes(y = dom_simpson, color = "dom_simpson")) +
geom_line(aes(y = dom_shannon, color = "dom_shannon")) +
facet_grid(REGION ~ .) +
labs(x = "Year", y = "Effective Number of Species", color = "Diversity") +
scale_colour_manual(values = c("darkturquoise", "magenta", "blue"), 
labels=c("Richness", "Shannon diversity", "Simpson Diversity")) +
ggtitle("Reef Fish Biodiversity in the FKNMS") +
theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

Thank you in advance for any tips and advice!

Comment: You should combine all your dom_x variables using e.g., `gather` from the `tidyr` package (http://tidyr.tidyverse.org/). Then you should be able to plot the data much more effectively. Without a sample data set it is hard to directly help you.

Comment: thank you for your help!